# Wordpress Site on AWS Free Tier

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS. I am looking for step by step guide on installing and hosting a wordpress site on AWS instalce using AWS free tier. Also I have a domain name registered over "Domains.Google", need a guide on how to point the domain on this Wordpress site. Thanks for all support being extended by colleagues here.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/projects/wordpress/), which includes a very quick way to launch a WordPress server. Please note, however, that the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) only includes a "Free Trial" for Lightsail for the first month.

Please note that the Free Tier is only intended as a way to "try the cloud". It is not intended for production workloads.